# How to use viewbinding in menu items

Tags: android, kotlin, binding, menu

The problem that I faced is I cannot retrieve the binding id of my menu items.
**HomeFragment ->includes(HomeActivity) ->includes(BottomNavigation)**

```
 //bottom navigation
    fun getBottomNavigation(){
           val bottomNavigation = binding!!.includeBottomNavigation.bottomNavigation
           bottomNavigation.itemIconTintList = null
            bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelected)
       }
 private val mOnNavigationItemSelected = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{ menuItem ->
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
```

//the issue what is, I want to use binding. navigation_home but it doesnot occur

```
 return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.navigation_chapter -> {
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.navigation_store -> {
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
            }
            false
        }
```

```
//menu items   
 <menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="" />
        
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_notification"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_notification"
            android:title="" />
    </menu>
```